# How to parse ISO8061 to date without timezone

Tags: json, swift, timezone, dateformatter

I receive data from the server in the JSON format and one field is `date` which holds year, month and day:

`"date": "2018-03-11",`

I don't need exact time, just day and month. I used a DateFormatter with locale but I'm still receiving date from the UTC timezone. I live in CET (+1)/ CEST (+2) timezone so I wonder what is the best approach to parse this date. When I receive `"2018-03-11"` from server I would like to get:

```
date = 2018-03-11 00:00:00
```

date formatter:

```
private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
       let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.iso8601)
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "pl_PL")

        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        return dateFormatter
    }()
```

Comment: The thing is that if you only need day and month you still need a time zone... When Friday starts in France it's still Thursday in Britain.

Comment: Provide what you have so far.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález so how should the date from the server look like?

Comment: @bcr I've updated the post with the DateFormatter

Comment: The Time zones in ISO 8601 are represented as local time (with the location unspecified), as UTC. If you receive "2018-03-11" you would like the zero padded hours/minutes - correct? In that case, fix the server side for sending the json across.

Comment: I guess the server time zone is implicit. If you want to use that same zone, figure out which one it is and hard-code it. Otherwise, you can always use the device's time zone. It all depends on what the date means or what it's used for.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález ok, but how should I define the timezone if it is variable (+1/ +2)?

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about Swift (sorry for messing around, he he) but decent time libraries accept time zones like "Europe/Paris".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")

let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
            dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.init(identifier: "UTC")
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            return dateFormatter
        }()

    print(dateFormatter.date(from: "2018-03-11"))
```

Comment: unfortunately it returns wrong date: for example for `2018-03-11` I got : `date = 2018-03-10 23:00:00 +0000;`

Comment: ok, thanks. I don't know if it's the best solution but it works 